# What is the average active install rate for established Android apps?

Tags: android

Google has yielded a few results to this question, but they all seem to be answers for apps that have very few installs or have not been around long.

I have an app that has been on the market for about 2.5 years and has about 1.3 million installs. In the past year, the active install rate has consistently dropped from what was >50% to now being 27%. I guess I just want to know how this compares to others of similar size.

My apologies if this isn't the correct place for this. I know there's an Android section, but it doesn't really seem to be for devs.

Comment: Both of my apps are around the 30% range.  They are both under 10k installs.

Comment: If you are still interested, you may want to see my answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969191/what-is-a-good-active-installs-rate-for-a-free-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My App (Beer or no Beer - Drinking Game) is also around the 30% range, is on the Market for half a year (no advertisment) and has over 7000 downloads right now. I think it really depends on the kind of app. Because mine is a drinking game many people will deinstall it after the weekend.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celticwolf.alex&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5jZWx0aWN3b2xmLmFsZXgiXQ..

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have 1800 downloads totaly , and my active install rate is 81.54% right now. Its trending between  78-82 %. 
My app is for checking balance on some lunchcoupons. It has a high ratio of active users that check their balance a couple of times a month. I guess the ratio is highly depending on what kind of application it is.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is around 75-83% for a news reader type app. I have another app that is getting around 60-72%. For the first time, I had a daily loss of active installs even with the new installs. If 30% is the average, then I am feeling pretty good about my record.