# What is a good "active installs" rate for a free Android app?

Tags: android

My free app has received many positive reviews and has a 4.5 star rating on the Android Market, but the active install rate is less than 40%, meaning more than half the people who download it uninstall it.

Is this normal? I would assume a highly-rated app would have closer to 100% install rate.

Comment: This may be sorta off topic but it's quite useful and has a good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like there is no official data from Google about this, but I did find this discussion:

> Here is an estimate from data collected from a few friendly developers.
>
> The best or essential 
>    - ~ dozen free apps, have a retention ratio above 75%
>    - ~ 100 free apps, have a retention ratio above 50%
>
> Rest stay below 50% after the first month and average at around ~30%.
>
> Paid apps work in a different way for obvious reasons.

[Android Market Discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=3f21d1b31b9015d8&hl=en)

Comment: It probably has as much to do with other factors such as: Can folks tell if your app does what they want it to without installing it and without too much reading? Is your app useful over a period of time?  For example, I installed an mDNS utility app that was very useful to me for about 3 days, then I uninstalled it.  It was a good app, but I didn't need it anymore.

Comment: Good points. Thank you very much!